# MacBook Pro 13 resolution problem?

Tags: macbook-pro

I just bought a MacBook Pro 13.
whenever I play a game that has lower resolution than 1280-800 I get two big black rectangles on both side of the screen, instead of the screen entirely filled.

Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the game is not widescreen enabled (but 4:3). This usually happens with ports of old games, from the times, when 4:3 (or close to 4:3) resolutions were common *(like 640x480, 800x600, 1024x768, 1280x1024)*. Look for resolution settings in the game and change it to something closer to 16:10 and the black bars will be smaller.

Comment: thanks @mspasov but in game only three options are there 640x480, 800x600 and 1024x768

Comment: Then I don't think that there is a way to make it run widescreen on your monitor (16:10). However if you connect an external 4:3 monitor the game will run on "full screen".